# Subjunctive in If clause

Tags: american-english

Here is my question which I came across-The context is present;
"If I could touch the water, I would feel it was cold."
Why it is written as "It was cold"? Shouldn't it be "It is cold"? Does " It was cold" represent some subjunctive as we do not know whether it is cold or not? If it is so, can we use to say " it were cold"

Comment: You definitely should not say *were*. Maybe you should have 300 years ago—I don't know. But here, both *was* and *is* are grammatical.

Comment: "Was" is the logical choice, since it has nothing to do with past time, but modal remoteness as already conveyed by the use of "could" and "would". This "was" is called a modal preterite for obvious reasons. "Were" here is not subjunctive (there's no past subjunctive in English), it's called irrealis mood, but in any case it would be something of a hypercorrection and definitely best avoided.

Comment: But when we should use "is"? If we are certain that it is cold then only we can say "is", isn't it? If "is" is appropriate for this context then why one should use "was"?

Comment: Because it's a matter of modality, remoteness from factuality. You can use "is" if you prefer, but it doesn't reflect the same counterfactuality that "was" does.

Comment: Does remoteness from factuality represent uncertainity of the situation, it is what u mean? Like if I say" If I were a king, I would rule all the world" Here "were" represent remoteness from factuality, is it so u intend to say? Is "were 'here is the same as "was" there?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is perfectly normal in English to use modal preterite "was" for such constructions. Are you a native speaker?

Comment: No I am not.But in American english people prefer to use "were" for such remoteness from factuality. British says " If I was...." but they say " If I were.." so in that way is it not appropriate to say "......it were cold"

Comment: @user182751: The way to look at this is to accept that English only really has two tenses - ***present*** and ***not-present*** (which includes "contrafactual" and "hypothetical" as well as "past").

Comment: Well then, just use it. It would certainly not be the choice in BrE, though; at least not in examples like yours.

Comment: The subjunctive 'were' is only used in the 'if' clause (the adverbial clause); not in the main clause.  If I were to touch the water, I would know that it was cold.'  When 'if' is explicit, then 'were' can be changed to 'was' -- the whole reason for the faulty agreement of 'were' is to signal an elided 'if'.

Comment: @AmI what is explicit "if"? And why it is "was" in the main clause and why not "is". Please , elaborate it as i am not a native speaker.

Comment: Both of the examples you have given (was and it) are correct, but both also imply that you KNOW the water to be cold. If you want to convey a sense that you could check the temperature if you could touch the water, you would say "If I could touch the water, I would feel *whether* it was/is cold." In this case, you could, at a stretch, use "were" in AmE, but I think it sounds strained (I'm a native AmE speaker).

Comment: 'Explicit' means 'not implied'. ('Implicit' means 'implied', which means 'assumable', 'elided' or 'reduced'.)  The main clause is part of a hypothetical situation, so the past tense is used to indicate that it is not in the present timeline. (That is an overloaded use of the past tense.)

Comment: @AmI Can we say then - If I could touch the water, i would feel that it had been heated." Had been heated" would be more appropriate than "has been heated" ? Which one would be more appropriate?

Comment: @user182751 - The verb in a relative clause ([that] ...) does not need to share the tense of the calling clause.  (ex: "I know that you went.")  You would use 'had' or 'has' depending on when the water was actually heated.

Answer (score 1):

I would only use

> If I could touch the water, I would feel that it is cold.

if I needed to emphasize the expectation of perceiving it's known cold temperature. Thus, I think I would prefer, as Max indicates, reconstructing the sentence. Another reconstruction might be

> If I could touch the water it would chill me.

(And I seem to want to add "... to the bone." :-)

If it were not me, myself, feeling the cold, it would make a bit more sense to use the present. But I'd still reconstruct it:

> That water is cold. If you could touch it, you would know that it is so.

Otherwise, I'd go with non-present in describing the resultant state, keeping the parallel with the subjunctive "would know" or "would feel" --

> ... that it was cold.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct was that it should more correctly be "were", as the question is describing a **hypothetical situation**, and it's therefore the **subjunctive mood**

http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/

However, *"If I could touch the water, I would feel it were cold."* seems wrong to me.  If I was to rewrite it, I think I'd say

> If I could touch the water, I would feel **that** it is cold.

or

> If I could touch the water, I would feel its coldness.

Comment: As a comment, I don't think the *that* makes any difference. I think both *is* and *was* are grammatical in the OP's question, with or without *that*.

Comment: But when we should use "is"? If we are certain that it is cold then only we can say "is", isn't it? If "is" is appropriate for this context then why one should use "was"?

Comment: Use it whenever you please. It's the same either way, in this construction.

Comment: Ahem. "If I **were** to rewrite it ..." (Or am I being American here? ;-)

Comment: @JoelRees no your right (sic) :)